# How can I resize a ID2D1Bitmap?

Tags: direct2d

I have an ID2D1Bitmap . I would like to create a copy which has 50% less pixels...and then I would like to draw that.

Can you show me how to do that? I mean with working code.
The most obvious solution fails...That is to create a compatible target. I get unsupported bitmap pixel format after calling this.

HRESULT hr = context->CreateCompatibleRenderTarget(
D2D1::SizeF(10.0f, 10.0f),
&pCompatibleRenderTarget
);

Comment: You cannot "resize" an ID2D1Bitmap as this is a GPU resource, you'll have to go through the GPU pipeline again, ie: you can draw it on another using ID2D1DeviceContext::DrawImage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1_1/nf-d2d1_1-id2d1devicecontext-drawimage(id2d1image_d2d1_point_2f_constd2d1_rect_f__d2d1_interpolation_mode_d2d1_composite_mode) (in a BeginDraw/EndDraw session). That device context can have been created from ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateCompatibleRenderTarget for example.

Comment: I get unsupported bitmap pixel format after calling CreateCompatibleRenderTarget

Comment: show some reproducible code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example